# Modifying a simple jQuery multiplier

Tags: jquery

I have a function that multiplies a supplied value and outputs the result to the screen. It is working great but I am trying to perform a multiplication to the number if the value is above a set amount.

For example if greater than 10 + 20%, if greater than 20 + 40%.

Here is what I have so far.

```
                jQuery(function($){
                    var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                        currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';
                    $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                        if (!(this.value < 1)) {
                            var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value);
                            $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                        }
                    });
                });
```

I tried doing this if an if else statement but it didn't work and I have no idea why.

```
                jQuery(function($){
                    var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                        currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';
                    $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                        if (!(this.value < 1)) {
                            var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value);
                            $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                        } else if (!(this.value < 10)) {
                            var newPrice = price * 1.2; 
                            var product_total = parseFloat(newPrice * this.value);
                            $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                        } else {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Greatly appreciate the feedback.

Comment: At a glance, you're missing the `if` after your `else`. `else` on its own can't take a condition, that's what `else if` is for.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, just updated it an if else statement but still no joy :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a really simply if / else if / else condition:

```
var amounts = [1,5,12,37,50];
var price = 100;
$.each(amounts, function(idx, element) {
    if (element < 10) {
        console.log('Amount is: ' + element + ' price is normal: ' + price);
    } else if (element <=20 ) {
        console.log('Amount is: ' + element + ' price has 10% discount: ' + (price - (price * 0.1)));
    } else if (element <= 40) {
        console.log('Amount is: ' + element + ' price has 20% discount: ' + (price - (price * 0.2)));
    } else {
        console.log('Amount is: ' + element + ' price has 45% discount: ' + (price - (price * 0.45)));
    }
});
```

Output:

```
Amount is: 1 price is normal: 100  
Amount is: 5 price is normal: 100  
Amount is: 12 price has 10% discount: 90  
Amount is: 37 price has 20% discount: 80  
Amount is: 50 price has 45% discount: 55
```

I suggest you to not mix vanila js and jquery once you are using jQuery. Syntactically right, but more readable, if you are using `$(this).val()` instead of `this.value`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I need to figure out now how to implement with my dynamic WooCommerce data but what you have outlined is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your `if` statements doesn't make sense. If the value is greater than or equal to 1, it will always enter the first block and will never hit the `else if` block. I'd recommend organizing the if/if-else-else in the reverse order, and use "greater than/equal to" instead of "not less than" logic. So using your example:

```
                jQuery(function($){
                    var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                        currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';
                    $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                        if (this.value >= 10) {
                            var newPrice = price * 1.2; 
                            var product_total = parseFloat(newPrice * this.value);
                            $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                        } else if (this.value >= 1) {
                            var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value);
                            $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                        } else {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    });
                });
```

This way the logic is correct, not to mention easier to read.